# how to sort mysql two different values?

Tags: java, mysql

I have 2 Tables and i join them.

I have a `special_id` field, if the `special_id` field is `> -1` then they should be printed out **before** the ones with `special_id < -1`.
And then i want to order them by `name`.

How can i do that?

A simple `order by special_id asc, name desc` isnt enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its the other way around:

ORDER BY special_id DESC, name ASC

You have to split your query in 2 (one for the case of special_id > -1, the other for special_id < -1, both sorted by username), add a constant to each of them, UNION them, then sort by the constant added earlier

Example:

```
(SELECT 1 AS main_order, t.* FROM table t WHERE special_id > -1 )
UNION
(SELECT 2 AS main_order, t.* FROM table t WHERE special_id < -1 )
ORDER BY main_order, name DESC
```

Comment: this sounds good! what do you exactly mean with add a constant?

Comment: mh.. somehow it doesnt work how i want it to be.. :/

if i do it like you say.. the order seems to be random...

Comment: the order seems to be random right now...
table looks like this:
name special_id

ernst 27388
tim   39005
masi  33385
dorfi  27005

so it isnt sorted by name... but special_id < -1 or > -1 is right sorted

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

```
SELECT IF(special_id > -1 , 1 , 0 ) AS order_help  , m.*  FROM mytable m    
ORDER BY order_help DESC, name DESC
```

Comment: mh.. thats not exactly what i want... because this is the same as mine... but just with another if :) 
and this doesnt sort them the way i want..

Comment: i think you mean to : ORDER BY order_help DESC, name DESC ?

Comment: I think he needs first part of the resultset (the ones > -1) ordered by name desc, and only after those, the ones with special_id < -1 ordered also by name descending

Comment: exactly tudor, thats what i want!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN special_id > -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END orderValue,t.* FROM table1 t)
 UNION
(SELECT CASE WHEN special_id > -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END orderValue,t.* FROM table2 t)
ORDER BY orderValue,name DESC;
```

Here are my results :

```
/*************************/
  | orderValue | name   |
  |     0      | foo    |
  |     0      | bar    |
  |     1      | foobar |
  |     1      | barfoo |
/************************/
```

Hope that helps.